# Color Profiles: Please explain

Tags: color-profile

I have requested for a print house to complete a workpiece for me. One of their requested for preparing the item is "Please don't use color profiles". I don't know what this means and therefore don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: What software is the work made in?

Comment: Why on earth wojld they request that?

Answer (score 1):

While this is a very complex subject, the simple answer is that many programs (Illustrator, Photoshop, etc) will embed a color profile when you save a file in various file formats. You can choose NOT to embed a profile, and this is what the print house is asking you to do.
Color profiles characterize the color rendering capabilities of various hardware, including monitors, printers, plotters, proofers, etc. 
The challenges of maintaining color fidelity across programs and devices is a difficult part of computer graphics. Look for more information online.